# Spark - scala Window-lead function and case statment result is not as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is the dataframe

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Alice", 1,"2016-05-01"),
  ("Alice",1 ,"2016-05-03"),
  ("Alice", 2,"2016-05-04"),
  ("Bob", 3,"2016-05-01")
).toDF("name","value" ,"date")
```

if leading row's `df("value")` is same (partition by `name`) I want to say "Nochange" otherwise subtract 1 day from date column

```
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date")
df.withColumn("result", 
  when(lead(df("value"), 1).over(windowSpec) === df("value") , "NOCHANGE" )
  .otherwise(date_sub(df("date"),1))
).show()
```

This statement's output is

```
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
| name|value|      date|    result|
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|Alice|    1|2016-05-01|  NOCHANGE|
|Alice|    1|2016-05-03|2016-05-02|
|Alice|    2|2016-05-04|2016-05-03|
|  Bob|    3|2016-05-01|2016-04-30|
+-----+-----+----------+---------
```

But expected output is

```
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
| name|value|      date|    result|
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|Alice|    1|2016-05-01|  NOCHANGE|
|Alice|    1|2016-05-03|2016-05-02|
|Alice|    2|2016-05-04|  NOCHANGE| //as it is last value of Alice partition
|  Bob|    3|2016-05-01|  NOCHANGE|//as no leading value in Bob partition
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Additional if I have multiple columns to compare (value1 , value2, value3) what would be best approach to compare consecutive rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `lead(..., 1)` returns `null` when it is the last row in the partition, and you are not handling them correctly. See this:

```
df.withColumn("result" , lead(col("value"), 1).over(windowSpec)).show
+-----+-----+----------+------+
| name|value|      date|result|
+-----+-----+----------+------+
|Alice|    1|2016-05-01|     1|
|Alice|    1|2016-05-03|     2|
|Alice|    2|2016-05-04|  null|
|  Bob|    3|2016-05-01|  null|
+-----+-----+----------+------+
```

Try this instead:

```
df.withColumn("result" , lead(col("value"), 1).over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("result",
    when(col("result") === col("value") || col("result").isNull, "NOCHANGE")
    .otherwise(date_sub(col("date"), 1))
  ).show

+-----+-----+----------+----------+
| name|value|      date|    result|
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|Alice|    1|2016-05-01|  NOCHANGE|
|Alice|    1|2016-05-03|2016-05-02|
|Alice|    2|2016-05-04|  NOCHANGE|
|  Bob|    3|2016-05-01|  NOCHANGE|
+-----+-----+----------+----------+
```

If you have multiple columns to compare, you are going to need multiple `result` columns, and then use `&&` to create your final result. Maybe something like:

```
val df2 = ....toDF("name", "value1", "value2", "date")

df.withColumn("nextValue1", lead(col("value1"), 1).over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("nextValue2", lead(col("value2"), 1).over(windowSpec))
  .withColumn("result",
    when(
      (col("nextValue1") === col("value1") && col("nextValue2") === col("value2")) || col("nextValue1").isNull,
      "NOCHANGE"
    ).otherwise(date_sub(col("date"), 1))
  ).drop("nextValue1").drop("nextValue2")
```

Comment: Thanks @David Griffin..any pointer on if I have multiple columns to compare what will be the efficient way to compare rows?

Comment: Just added that a couple minutes ago.